# Is there a way in Jface to specify the size of the icon to be used with a node in a Treeviewer?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using a TreeViewer to display the status of several items. The status should be displayed using icons. I am currently displaying colored lights to indicate the status of each node. I now need to display 2 different statuses for each item and would like each to have its own icon.

Because I have not been able to find a way to add multiple icons per node I am combining the icons into a single image that is twice as wide (32x16) as each original icon (16x16). This works except that at some point before the icon is displayed it is squished back to the original size (16x16).

Is there a way in Jface to specify the size of the icon to be used with a node in a Treeviewer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Icons are resized to the dimensions of the first rendered image. If you want to use multiple Items use a Tree with multiple Columns or use a decorating LabelProvider to use decoration for a base image instead of different icons.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that answers my question very well